# Lemon Graph Library C++ - Directed Graph

Tags: c++, path-finding, directed-graph, lemon-graph-library

I am looking at Lemon to handle my pathfinding, since it has search and shortest paths algorithms, among other things.

The thing is, I am already stuck right at the start in understanding how Lemon works, and they have a tutorial but no forum to ask.

My understanding of a directed graph is that you have a node, and it can link or not link to another node and then you have a weight on it.

Example:

```
     A    B    C
A    0    1    0
B    1    0    5
C    0    0    0
```

In this, `A` is connected to `B` with a weight of 1, `C` is connected to nothing (so once you get to `C` you are stuck), and `B` connects to `A` with a value of 1 and `B` connects to `C` with a value of 5.

The tutorial says to do something like this:

```
ListDigraph g;
ListDigraph::Node A = g.addNode();
ListDigraph::Node B = g.addNode();
ListDigraph::Node C = g.addNode();
```

So now I have a graph `g` with the three nodes. Now what? Where / how do I add the connectivity information as well as the weight values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Lemon tutorial

```
  ListDigraph g;

  ListDigraph::Node x = g.addNode();
  ListDigraph::Node y = g.addNode();
  ListDigraph::Node z = g.addNode();

  g.addArc(x,y);
  g.addArc(y,z);
  g.addArc(z,x);
```

Never used this library mind, I'm just quoting what I've read.

Comment: yeah I read this.. and in my question I have the code you have written.. but how dose this answer my question?

Comment: Your first was question 'how do i add the connectivity info'. It's there in my answer, the last three lines, its not in the code you quoted.

Comment: I also do not know this library. However, you asked how to add connectivity information to the graph. It looks like that this method 'addArc' does just that -- except that there is no weight.

Comment: oh, I thought this was some kind of curved line... so this is saying X connected to Y and Y to Z and Z to X... ? So in my example.. it would be g.addArc(a,b), (b,a), (b,c).. is that correct? But  istill see no infomation on weights?

Comment: Seems for weight, you must use a data structure called an ArcMap. But as I say, no experience with this library.

Comment: @AJynks: OK, arc is pretty standard terminology for a connection between nodes (or vertices as they're also known). But if you didn't know it I guess it would be confusing.

Comment: your being very helpful Jahhaj

Answer (score 0):

LEMON uses slightly different terminology than most graph theory texts, but in my opinion that makes using the library a bit easier.

Firstly, the difference between an edge and an arc in LEMON is simply that an edge is an *undirected* edge between two nodes, and an arc is a *directed* edge.

---

As for adding edges and weights and whatnot, graphs themselves only manage nodes and edges/arcs, the only data associated with each is an integral identifier.

You can find this identifier using:

```
graph.id(node);
```

To attach pieces of data to the nodes/edges, you use maps. There are a few different types of maps, but they generally boil down to a `NodeMap`, `EdgeMap`, or `ArcMap` - and, as you probably guessed, they are associative maps of `<Node, V>`, `<Edge, V>` and `<Arc, V>`, respectively, where `V` is the value type (which can be anything that has a default constructor).

---

To add edges (in an undirected graph) or arcs (in a digraph), you simply create the two nodes and then use `.addEdge(n1, n2)` or `.addArc(n1, n2)`.

For example:

```
ListDigraph graph;

ListDigraph::Node n1 = graph.addNode();
ListDigraph::Node n2 = graph.addNode();

ListDigraph::Arc a = graph.addArc(n1, n2);
```

And to associate a some value with that arc:

```
ArcMap<std::string> arcMap;

arcMap[a] = "This is an arc value!";
```